# Computed Properties in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm currently converting my Database Persistence from `Dapper` to `EF`.
Is there a way to fetch a computed properties without including
the related objects?

```
public class Invoice{
  private decimal _total=0;
  public IEnumerable<InvoiceItem> Items{get;set;}
  public decimal Total{
    get=> Items.Sum(x=>x.Total);
    private set=> _total=value;
  }
}
public class InvoiceItem{
    public decimal Total{get;set;}
}
```

The `Total` Property in `Invoice` Class is saved in the database.
The way I fetch it currently is by `joining/including` the `InvoiceItem` to the `Invoice`, since the `Total` Property is stored in the database, is there a way to just query the `Invoice` along with the `Total`?

Edit: Here's the actual part of the Entity of my Project, it depends on other tables to calculate the Total.

```
public class Invoice{

    //other properties
    public decimal Total{
    get => CalculateTotal();
    set => _ = value;
    }

private decimal CalculateTotal()
{
    var previousStatementTotal = PreviousStatement?.Total ?? 0;
            var miscChargeTotal = LeaseMiscellaneousChargeInvoice?.Total ?? 0;
    return            
        previousStatementTotal+ 
        RentsInvoice.Sum(x => x.Total) +
        RentsInvoice.Sum(x => x.ValueAddedTaxAfterDiscount) +
        RentsInvoice.Sum(x => x.WitholdingTaxAfterDiscount) +
        miscChargeTotal+
        Utilities.Sum(x => x.Total) +
        Utilities.Sum(x => x.ValueAddedTaxAfterDiscount) +
        DeductionInvoices.Sum(x => x.Amount) +
        OtherCharges.Sum(x => x.Total);
    }
}
```

I've already did what @Steve-Py suggested and it works.

Comment: I don't get it. Is it computed or persisted, now? What's the point in having the setter set a field and the getter never read it?

Comment: Its a computed property that is also persisted on the database.

Comment: Pick one. Either compute and then persist the computed value. Downside: you need to track changes to the items and recompute and update. Or have it be a computed property by SQL join and sum. Downside: actual Join needed.

Comment: This property in my actual code depends on 4 different tables, I'm able to make it work by SQL Join in EF. Just wondering if there's a way that it would work like `Dapper` where you could fetch the `Invoice` including the `Total` property. I guess Joining is the only way.

Comment: @forgetaboutme have you tried this `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] // Annotation for computed property
    public decimal Total { get; private set; }` and this `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().Property(i => i.Total).HasComputedColumnSql("[Total]"); // Specify the computed column name
}`

Comment: "I'm currently converting my Database Persistence from Dapper to EF" - there's your mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of a problem with your code in that your setter sets a private member but the getter always goes to the Items. For a start if you want a "Total" that can be overridden:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceItem> Items{ get; set; }
    private decimal? _total = null;
    public decimal Total
    {
        get => _total ??= Items.Sum(x=>x.Total);
        private set => _total = value;
    }
}
```

This in itself isn't ideal because if Items are added/removed or have their total changed, the invoice total will be stale, so you would need to consciously clear that _total or re-calculate whenever Items changed.

EF does support computed columns where your Invoice table can have a computed column for the total based on the related invoice items. There the invoice entity would just need a Total column marked as "Computed":

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public decimal Total { get; set; }
```

The downside of this is that it doesn't look at the current state of Items, so if you are adding/removing items or changing item totals in your entities, the Invoice Total column won't be refreshed until you call `SaveChanges` which could be problematic if you are relying on Invoice.Total while modifying the invoice items.

Summary columns like that are often a view concern, not really a domain one. For instance if I have a set of search results and I want to see the Total for each invoice returned, I don't want to have to eager load all items to get it. Projecting an InvoiceSearchResultViewModel is a good way to address this without introducing stuff like this to the Invoice entity:

```
public class InvoiceSearchResultViewModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    // other Invoice related details we want to see...
    public decimal Total { get; set; } // Not a value in invoice entity or table.
}

var results = await _context.Invoices
    .Where(x => /* Search criteria */)
    .Select(x => new InvoiceSearchResultViewModel
    {
        InvoiceId = x.InvoiceId,
        // Other fields from Invoice or related entities....
        Total = x.InvoiceItems.Sum(ii => ii.Total)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

This has the benefit of not requiring any eager loading or tripping lazy loading (if enabled) and generally results in smaller, more efficient queries being executed. You can avoid the cruft of writing that `Select` statement out every time by leveraging Automapper and its `ProjectTo` method which makes it a one-liner. It helps to split concerns between view (consumer) concerns and domain (entity) concerns. Entities serve to represent the domain while presenting that data in a way that suit views or API consumers can be served by dedicated view models.

Comment: Great explanation. With the approach that you've provided, I have to do this`Include(x=>x.Items)` to get the Total, right? This is what Im trying to avoid, as I've said, I came from using `Dapper` so just wondering if there's a same way to fetch the Invoice.Total the same way Dapper does.

Comment: If you use projection with a view model you don't need to use `Include`, but if you want to fetch an entity and have the total accessible then you would need it, or ensure you have Lazy Loading enabled so that code that accesses that Total can fetch the items if needed.

Comment: I've updated my question, I've included the actual Entity in my project, I've learned what projection is. I agree that `Total` is a view concern, but if you would need to store the `Total` in your entity, how would you approach it? How will you calculate or set the `Total` field?

Comment: At an entity level there are trade offs. Using a database-computed value gives you something you can use in query expressions. I believe you might be able to use a setter to update it, but ultimately the DB determines the "real" value which is only refreshed when saved/reloaded. Computing it within the entity requires Items to be loaded, eager or lazy and it cannot be used within Linq2SQL expressions like Where clauses. Your expressions have to sum up from Items explicitly. So I'd lean towards DB computed.